# Why is an i variable included in a loop definition if it's not being used therein?

Tags: javascript

I’m doing an exercise on Code School, and I don’t understand how the loop works.

There is an `i`, but I don’t see it used. Normally you use it somewhere. Otherwise, what is the for loop for?

```
var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];
var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function(input, queue) {
  var length = queue.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    input = queue.shift()(input);
  }
  return input;
};

alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

Comment: It's not used within the body of the loop, but it is used to terminate the loop after the correct number of iterations.

Comment: `i < length` <-- looks like it is being used

Comment: because someone doesn't know about `forEach`.

Comment: Knowing about `forEach` doesn't mean you'll always use it. A `for` loop is fine. They're faster. They're supported by IE8 (although forEach can be polyfilled easily enough). No need to pick on the older iteration method. ;)

Comment: that `for `can be easy replaced with this simpler code: `while( queue.length ){  input = queue.shift()(input);  };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *have* to use the `i` all the time, but its there if you need it. Normally if you dont use the `i` you use instead whats called a `for-each` loop instead. `for-each` is just a simpler way of writing a `for` loop without needing an explicit index variable.

Javascript doesn't have a simple `for-each` loop as part of the language, and I think they want to keep it as a `for` loop just to keep the lesson simple, but if you want to learn more about `for-each` in javascript, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) question

Answer (score 6):

It's used in the test to see if you have reached the end of the loop or not (the second part of the `for` statement).

Answer (score 4):

Without the loop boundaries defined in the loop.
The loop will never end!

Answer (score 4):

The variable is simply used to count the iterations of the loop.  The loop ends after *length* iterations as kept track of by *i*.

In this case *i* serves no other purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It is being used - to ensure that the loop iterates `length` times.

If you are going to count from `0` to `length - 1`, you need something to keep track of the count, right?